# Variable is not declared error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to get visual basic to work through Visual Studio 2013. I began the course a week ago so I'm pretty clueless. All I know is how to create a new project, in general select Form and in declarations select Activated. In the end I end up with the following code :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
        a = 3
        b = 2
        c = a + b
        Print(c)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Pretty sure something needs to be deleted. I tried declaring a,b and c with Int but that didn't help and I'm still getting the same error. I tried deleting everything except

```
Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    a = 3
    b = 2
    c = a + b
    Print(c)
End Sub
```

but then I get the error Statement is not valid in a namespace.

Comment: You need to declare the variable. Just doing `a=3` is not going to work. You need to declare as someting i.e. `Dim a As Integer = 3`. I've voted to close this as a typographical error. http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/variable-declaration

Comment: Why don't you look it up yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/variable-declaration

Comment: First rule of programming: always read language/API specs

Comment: @DipenShah Ah you beat my edit  xD

Comment: @TyCobb: Sorry :)

Comment: So is this fairly different than Visual Basic 6.0? We didn't use declaration like that I guess I'm in the wrong program.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare anything. In VB.NET you [declare variable with Dim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/variable-declaration) and specifying it's data type.

```
Dim a As Integer = 3
Dim b As Integer = 2
Dim c As Integer = a + b
```

Although they are similar, VB.NET and VS 6.0 are different.

Comment: I believe it's a misunderstanding. I think we used a different program at school and didn't need to declare the same way. Seems that VB.net is different than basic 6.0 so I will need to install that. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @DreaDk You still need to declare in VB6. I advise you to not touch VB6 unless you have a very good reason and to stick with VB.NET

Comment: As if I had a choice. My university tends to like VB6 a lot although I assume at this point it's pretty dead.

Comment: @DreaDk The VB6 forms engine is pretty dead.  The underlying language is the same as the VBA in Excel, though, so there is still some value to knowing it.  The declaration syntax given in the answer is mostly OK for VBA except that you can't assign a variable in the declaration.